# Facebook places graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

There is a way to know users checked-in in a place in this moment? For example I would to know people who have checked-in with facebook place in the place X in the last hour ...

Many thanks!

Stefano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using `FQL`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

You can query the `checkin` table for a specific `page_id` and constrain the query on the `timestamp` column.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/checkin/

Comment: thanks for your reply, Brian! 
But the checkin table that you have mentioned is available or do I have 
some permission? if I use the test console does not get any 
result ... 
(Http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/)

Comment: Huh, even their example doesn't work ... could be that you have to own the page. I notice in the Page graph API docs it says you need the 'friends_checkin' permission, but I don't know how a page would grant that. You might post to their dev forums and ask.